# How do I show in Chrome Web Tool the original directory structure of bundled Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, google-chrome-devtools

I have a project that produces JavaScript files which would be used by other multiple projects. These JavaScript files are copied to each of the projects' directories using a gulp task then the projects reference those files in their index.html. For a certain reason, the files needed to be bundled to a single file so the index.html would only reference one file instead of having the need to add a reference every time a new file is added to the source project. The files are now bundled and it can be debugged in Chrome Web Tool. However is there a way to keep the knowledge of the original file structure in the Chrome Web Tool even if the files are now bundled to a single file? Like being able to see files under their folders, etc. as if they were referenced one by one in the index.html.

I have tried [Source Maps](https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/05/24/what-are-javascript-source-maps/) but it seems like it's more on being able to debug a minified production code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I further tinkered with how the gulp plugin that bundles the files and its available options and found out that what I am trying to find is actually there. The gulp plugin is called [webpack-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-stream), basically *the* [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/) in Gulp.

Using the following webpack config options in the gulp file,

[image]

it will bundle the files into a single file and allow for debugging and being able to see the source files' folder structure like this:

[image]

The `bundled.js` file is the only file referenced in the index.html and the files shown in their original folder structure is under the `webpack://` node.